# Could a function be never called because of a context switch?

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

In the following code, the goal is to *doSomething()* if document is ready, otherwise, if document is loading, attach *doSomething()* as an event handler for where document is ready.

I wonder if there is a context switch / interrupt just after `(d.readyState=='loading')`, could it be that the handler gets attached after the DOM is loaded, and so `fn()` will never get called.

the code is the following:

```
(function(fn){
    var d=document;
    (d.readyState=='loading') ? d.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',fn) : fn();
})

(function(){
    doSomething();
});
```

if it is an actual problem, then what would be a correct solution.
Otherwise, why couldn't it happen?

Comment: Those functions are created but not called. There are no "context switches" in JavaScript.

Comment: @Pointy, the functions _are_ called. The formatting is a bit weird. It's an IIFE with an argument.

Comment: Ah I see, lack of semicolon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is a bit confusing as written.

Consider the following format:

```js
(function(fn){
  var d=document;
  d.readyState=='loading'
    ? d.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',fn)
    : fn();
})(function(){
  alert("hello")
});
```

The below is an argument of the [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE).

```
function(){
  alert("hello")
}
```

So, `fn` references the above function.

Given the above, `fn` is guaranteed to get called as long as the `DOMContentLoaded` fires and as long as there are no runtime errors on the same tick.

If `document.readyState` is `loading`, then the event handler would have been added on that same tick. At the earliest, the `DOMContentLoaded` would fire on the *next* tick. Otherwise, `fn` is called immediately.

To learn more about JavaScript's event loop, I highly recommend this video:

https://youtu.be/cCOL7MC4Pl0

Comment: You say "it would have been added on that same tick.". But what makes it this way? why couldn't there be a context switch? is the condition atomic?

Comment: @wp42 It sounds like you're over complicating it. Watch the video and see if you're questions are answered.

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah thanks for that great video. But yes, im still over complicating it and dont understand totally.

Comment: @wp42 Perhaps this can help. JavaScript code that is not asynchronous will always run on the same tick. Asynchronous code, at the earliest, will run on the next tick. `addEventListener` is synchronous.

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah So you are saying the the whole self-invoked funtion (the whole code) will run atomically - in the same tick? Second question: In the video (which is really great), is every round / loop is actually a "tick" you are talking about? Thanks mate you helped a lot !

Comment: @wp42 yes to both. The only part of that entire code that wouldn't run on the same tick is `fn` if `document.readyState` was `loading` when the code ran. The reason is because the `DOMContentLoaded` event would fire, at the earliest, on the next tick.

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah thanks for your answer, I marked it. If you have time, please see my related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54850944/in-javascript-runtime-what-is-the-difference-between-a-frame-of-the-stack-and