# In javascript runtime, what is the difference between a "frame" of the stack and a "message" of the queue?

Tags: javascript

In [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop), I'm looking at this piece of code:

```
function foo(b) {
  var a = 10;
  return a + b + 11;
}

function bar(x) {
  var y = 3;
  return foo(x * y);
}

console.log(bar(7)); //returns 42
```

And in the next paragraph, they say that each function bar, foo, are frames that are added to the stack.

But I don't understand where the queue comes to the picture; In that piece of code, where are the "messages" is the console.log() a message? How can we differ a message from a stack frame?

Comment: Perhaps reading this can help answer your question: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop

Comment: Is the queue only for events?

Comment: The documentation is misleading since they console.log a message but it likely isn&#39;t a message in the queue. It&#39;s likely just a normal message like this comment is a message to you. They overloaded the term. In the section under &quot;adding messages&quot; they use this language: In web browsers, messages are added anytime an event occurs and there is an event listener attached to it. So, yes, the queue is only for event listeners and asynchronous code (i.e. setTimeout).

Answer (score 0):

You could add some outputs to the function which function is actually running an *on stack* while running.

Every function call creates a new stack entry and this entry pops after/with returning the function.

For better visalizing and getting a `console.log`, the return value is chached in `temp` and returned after showing the message.

```js
function foo(b) {
    console.log('put foo on stack');
    var a = 10, temp
    temp = a + b + 11;
    console.log('pop foo from stack');
    return temp;
}

function bar(x) {
    console.log('put bar on stack');
    var y = 3, temp;
    temp = foo(x * y);
    console.log('pop bar from stack');
    return temp;
}

console.log(bar(7)); //returns 42
```

Comment: Hi! thanks for your answer, but this doesn't really answer my question. I understand that each functions runs on the stack. but I don't understand where the queue comes to the picture.

Comment: the queue has nothing to do with it. the queue puts an element at the end ans takes an element from start.